# Substituted for Angustura bitters in a lentil recipe?

Tags: substitutions

I have a recipe for Lentil Soup that calls for 3 drops Angustura bitters.  What can I use as a substitute?

Comment: IMO, 3 drops amounts to nothing ! you could skip it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

If you are keen on incorporating the flavor profiles of the Angostura bitters try putting a bit of cinnamon, cloves and nutmeg. When cooking the alcohol content will evaporate either way, so the only thing you're really after is the herbal taste of the beverage. Hope that helps :)